# Error in Chi-Square Test from tbl_summary() function

Tags: r, gt

I'm creating a table of descriptive statistics (code below) that continues to generate the following error for the `Mar` variable, which represents marital status in five levels ("Single", "Married", "Separated/Divorced", "Widowed", and "Other"):

`Warning for variable 'Mar': simpleWarning in stats::chisq.test(x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect   Error in s$close() : attempt to apply non-function`

```
table_desc <- analytical %>%
  tbl_summary(
    include = -id,
    by = exposure,
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                     all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
    label = list(SexF ~ "Sex",
                 Race ~ "Race",
                 Mar ~ "Marital Status",
                 AGE ~ "Age",
                 PROBLEMUse ~ "Substance Problem Use",
                 EDUCATION ~ "Education Level",
                 EMPLOYMENT ~ "Employment"),
  ) %>%
  add_overall() %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  add_p(test = list(all_continuous() ~ "kruskal.test",
                    all_categorical() ~ "chisq.test")) %>%
  bold_p() %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  gtsave(
    filename = "~/tables/Table_X.png"
  )
```

What does this error mean, and what is its solution?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the "Other" level of the `Mar` variable had too few observations to properly compare across groups (in one or two levels of the `exposure` variable, there were 0 participants endorsing the "Other" category). Aggregating this category with the "Widowed" category solved the problem!